# Solidify modifier not working correctly

Tags: modeling, modifiers, solidify-modifier

I am trying to make an interior for one of my models. I decided to use a solidify modifier to give it thickness on the inside. Some faces are extruding inwards nicely and others are not.

So, what have I tried? I have checked for and fixed; non-manifolded faces; loose geometry; interior faces. I have also; applied all the scale and rotation; manually converted the whole mesh to quads; removed any modifiers in the modifier stack; and also checked the face orientation is correct. I have also tried the complex setting on the solidify modifier and tweaked some of the options and I also did that on the simple setting. I also added a vertex group but that didn't make thing any better. Non of these have changed anything and I am starting to wonder if its not possible to make an interior using the solidify modifier and if I should instead be using booleans but I don't want to, as the result won't be too accurate. The modifier also distorts in certain places where its just a flat surface.

If you have any ideas on how to fix this, I would be much appreciated if commented on the post.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/863fbf2c096342388e65ffc9af4f91aa

Comment: I've created a new Solidify modifier to come back to default settings and it seems to work fine, except of course the faces are going to overalp, you can't avoid that with a complicated shape like this

Answer (score 1):

Under Blender 3.2 I checked both *Fill* and *Only Rim* under *Solidify* and it fixed this problem.